# Wordpress - Force the post permalink, post slug or post name with random values

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a wordpress set up, in which a series of special products are advertised, of which the name cannot be known, and whose pages cannot be entered.

With a 301 redirect I have solved that the product page cannot be entered.

And for greater security, I want the permanent link of the product to be a random string, that way no matter how much you try, you will not be able to enter the product page.

This is my PHP code:

```
function generateRandomUrl(){
    $char = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'h', 'H', 'i', 'I', 'j', 'J', 'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'o', 'O', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T', 'u', 'U', 'v', 'V', 'y', 'Y', 'x', 'X', 'z', 'Z');
    $cont = 0;
    $str = "";
    while ($cont < 20){
        $random = random_int(0, count($char)-1);
        $str .= $char[$random];
        $cont ++;
    }
    return $str;
}

$url = generateRandomUrl();
$post_data = array(
    'post_author' => $usuarioPropietario,
    'post_name' => $url, /* SLUG */
    'post_title' => $_POST['name'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['comment'],
    'post_excerpt' => $_POST['contenido'],
    'post_status' => 'pending', /* PENDIENTE */
    'ping_status' => 'closed',
    'post_type' => 'product',
);

$product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
```

My problem is that when the product is created with an administrator or editor user this works correctly. But when a user who has registered on the page, and who is not an administrator or editor, all the content is correct, but the 'post_name' does not work.

If I'm not mistaken, it is the value of the 'post_name' field that assigns the slug or permalink to the Woocommerce product.

Is there any way, to force the value of the post_name field? In the case of normal users, it seems to take the value of the 'post_title' field.

Comment: Using random characters to "hide/secure" a page is not the best way to go. Any SEO XML sitemap plugin will output your links defautly, and search engines can find and reference them. There are ways to achieve multiple versions of access restriction: roles, permissions, subscriptions, the owner only... Explain more about the restriction you need to implement. As for updating the slug on post save/update to a random string, I would go like @Tartarus explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hook your random function to action `save_post`.

You can use my below code in `functions.php` in

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'random_product_slug', 10, 3 );
function random_product_slug( $post_id, $post, $update ) {

    // Only run on product
    if ($post->post_type != 'product' || $post->post_status == 'auto-draft') {
        return;
    }

    // temporary remove this action because if will make loop when we call wp_update_post
    remove_action( 'save_post', 'random_product_slug', 10, 3 );

    // update product
    wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $post_id,
        'post_name' => generateRandomUrl()  // random slug/post_name
    ));

    // add this action to save_post again to make next product will have this action
    add_action( 'save_post', 'random_product_slug', 10, 3 );
}

function generateRandomUrl() {
    $char = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', 'a', 'A', 'b', 'B', 'c', 'C', 'd', 'D', 'e', 'E', 'f', 'F', 'g', 'G', 'h', 'H', 'i', 'I', 'j', 'J', 'k', 'K', 'l', 'L', 'm', 'M', 'n', 'N', 'o', 'O', 'p', 'P', 'q', 'Q', 'r', 'R', 's', 'S', 't', 'T', 'u', 'U', 'v', 'V', 'y', 'Y', 'x', 'X', 'z', 'Z');
    $cont = 0;
    $str = "";
    while ($cont < 20){
        $random = random_int(0, count($char)-1);
        $str .= $char[$random];
        $cont ++;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

> Is there any way, to force the value of the post_name field? In the
> case of normal users, it seems to take the value of the 'post_title'
> field.

Product slug only uses post_name. And all of the actions like create/update product will run through `save_post` action.

Comment: @icortazar That's my pleasure to help you.